# How to query for aggregate of two dimensional sparse matrix in PostgreSQl?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sparse-matrix, aggregates

Is there an efficient way to query for array_agg on sparse data as follows?
Rows with sparse elements need to get aggregated even if some are overlapped only partially.

Input

```
 ID  | tags
 ----|-------------
 a1  | {b1, b2}
 a2  | {b1, b3, b4}
 a3  | {b4, b5}
 a4  | {b6, b7}
 a5  | {b6, b8}
```

As you see, tags for a1, a2, and a3 do not overlap completely, but they should be aggregated for partial overlap.  Since the data are sparse, the size of aggregate will not be very big.

Expected output

```
 IDs          | tags
 -------------|-------------
 {a1, a2, a3} | {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5}
 {a4, a5}     | {b6, b7, b8}
```

It would be nice if the query gets done over night or so for some 200 thousand rows of data.

Thank you for help.

Toshi